# Specific heat capacity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

If two block with same mass but different specific heat capacity are heated up. When the two block are left to cool down, which block will have the lowest temperature?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! What are your thoughts? Please note that you are expected to have thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question. And it's important to detail where you're stuck and why, in order to attract good answers. You can consider checking the [advice on writing good questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).